# ETL from multiple MySQL databases

Tags: mysql, bigdata, amazon-redshift, etl, apache-kafka-streams

I have a system which extracts data from multiple MySQL databases with varying schemas, and performs many queries (with joins) and loads the output to another MySQL database.

These queries were once just a quick fix, but they’ve grown to over 10000 lines and thus choke the source databases.

I’m designing an efficient ETL pipeline by analyzing the SQL queries, but is there any temporary fix such as a tool which could analyze the queries and reduce the number of steps to reach the required schema?

Any help would be life-saving :)

Comment: I prefer to use both SQL and some 'real' programming language (eg, Perl) for any complex ETL.  Finding the optimal balance between them is tricky, but it is often worth it.  SQL is messy for string manipulation, the other language has lots of regexp power.  SQL is clean for blasting a change across an entire table; the other language is somewhat tedious.  Frankly, I would not trust any tool to have all the techniques you seem to need.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply. I agree, and I’m exploring various realtime ETL products, but I’m still struggling to find a way to fix it temporarily.

Comment: There is no "temporary" fix for 10K lines of code.

Comment: haha, can’t agree more. It was still worth a shot :)

Comment: You can check out Kafka Streams https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/streams/ (that you did tag the question for anyway) or KSQL: https://www.confluent.io/product/ksql/

Answer (score 0):

Rather than perform a query on many MySQL databases (which are optimized for writes), you should move all of your queries to the Redshift database (which is optimized for reads).

But to do this, you need the data.  Look into an ETL service that will clone *ALL* the data over to your Redshift.  We use Stitch Data but there are many players in the space.  You can set up multiple integrations, such that each MySQL db is pumping data into the same Redshift db (I'd recommend setting each up under a uniquely-named schema).

Once the data are all loaded, you can run your various queries in AWS Data Pipelines to create derived tables.  Each query can be each own job, that way you can monitor and modify on a per-query basis.